# SQLite removing a row, and reordering the rest of the rows

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm struggling with something relatively simple,

Let's say I have a table the first column is the primary key autoincrement

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | 22 |
| 2 | harry | 33 |
| 3 | greg | 44 |
| 4 | sally | 55 |

I want to remove row 2 and the rest of the items to automatically reorder so it looks like this

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | 22 |
| 2 | greg | 44 |
| 3 | sally | 55 |

I have tried every available bit of advice I can find online, they all involve deleting the table name from the sqlite_sequence table which doesn't work

is there a simple way to do archive what I am after?

Comment: You don't want to do this.  The `id` should identify the row using a fixed value, both across the database (i.e. used for foreign key relationships) and across time.  Use `row_number()` if you want to see a sequential value when you query the table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point/need to resequence the `id` column, as all values there will continue to be unique, even after deleting one or more records.  If you really wanted to *view* your data this way, you could delete the record mentioned, and then use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE id = 2;

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) id, name, age
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```